# Using getent group to get the number of users in a group in sh

Tags: sh

I want to print the number of users in a group named managers.

```
getent group managers | awk -F: '{print $4}' | awk -F, '{print}'
```

That line is printing their user login, but I want the count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
getent group managers | awk -F: '{n=split($4, a, ","); print n}'
```

Examples:

```
$ echo user:x:100:jason | awk -F: '{n=split($4, a, ","); print n}'
1
$ echo user:x:100:jason,bob,jim | awk -F: '{n=split($4, a, ","); print n}'
3
```

#### How it works

- `-F:`

  This tells sed to use `:` as the field delimiter
- `n=split($4, a, ","`)

  This tells sed to split the fourth field on commas.
- `print n`

  This tells sed to print the number of comma-separated elements found in field 4.

#### Simplification

We can compute the number and print it in one step:

```
getent group managers | awk -F: '{print split($4, a, ",")}'
```